# Angular 2 and VS Code Debug Issue: Reflect-Metadata

Tags: debugging, angular, visual-studio-code

I am working on simple projects for learning. Now i am reading about VS Code Debug but when i try to debug an Angular 2 project it always stop at here:

```
(function checkReflect() {
    if (!(Reflect && Reflect.getMetadata)) {
        throw 'reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators';
    }
})();
```

I tried on a Starter Project and CLI Projects. Always drop here. But all projects works well in browser without an error. Seems like an IDE problem.

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this? Perhaps consider answering the question yourself so others may find it.

Comment: No. I don't try debug in VS Code after this question. I use Chrome Developer Tools. I'll be back for this one after Angular 2 Final.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to debug your javascript based code is to debug it into browser debugger. All the IDEs have their own debugger tool and don't have any uniformity.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted - the question is not answered.

Comment: Not answer. But helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That means you do not have following dependencies installed in your project:

`npm install reflect-metadata crypto --save`

Comment: No. I have and no problem with browser (Chrome Dev Tools). Problem is in VS Code.

Comment: Okay but possibility may be that reflect-metadata is not installed in VSCode codebase, so check in there.